# geom_text overlapping with data points despite using nudge_x and nudge_y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to have text labels not overlap with the data points in a scatterplot made in `ggplot2`.

I've tried using the `nudge_` arguments in [`geom_text()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html):

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 resp = c(2, 3, 4))

ggplot(df, aes(resp, trt)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(aes(label = resp , nudge_y = 2, nudge_x = 2))
```

However, as we can see, the text overlaps with the point:
[image: current output]

Is there any way we can fix this? Also, what's the use of `nudge_x` and `nudge_y`? I don't quite get it from the manual.

Comment: move them outside the `aes`thetic, and chose sensible values ..`geom_text(aes(label = resp) , nudge_y = 0.5, nudge_x = 0.25)`

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that `nudge_x` & `nudge_y` should be outside of aesthetics.

```
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), resp = c(2, 3, 4))

ggplot(df, aes(resp, trt)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_text(aes(label = resp), nudge_y = -0.1)
```

This fixes the issue. I have reduced `nudge_y` values.

Here's the graph:
[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to move the label argument from within the geom_text() to ggplot() and use nudge_y values that proportionate to the scale used on your vertical(y) axis.

I'd have something like:

```
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), resp = c(2, 3, 4))

ggplot(df, aes(resp, trt, label = resp)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_text(nudge_y = -0.1)
```

Even better:

```
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), resp = c(2, 3, 4))

df %>% ggplot(aes(resp, trt, label = resp)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_text(nudge_y = -0.1)
```

PS: you would want to ensure your choice of values for nudge_y is determined by the scale used on your y-axis(vertical axis). Example, using nudge_y = 5 with your current data would mess up your plot because you have a smaller scale on the  vertical axis. Similarly, using nudge_y = -0.1 for a scale of 1000, 2000, 3000, ..., 15000 would not seem to have any effect on your plot.